# Significant figures reduction of solution

Tags: arithmetic

I have a problem which has to be answered using two significant figures from the solution value. 
My solution value is

x = 303.385789245434541

What should my answer be?

Thanks

Comment: How did you get that number? On a calculator?

Answer (score 2):

Answering just $300$ is perfectly fine in some contexts, but then it's not clear if the number of significant figures is one, two or three.

If you want to be explicit about the number of significant figures, you could either answer $3.0\cdot10^2$, or add the information in words, e.g. "$300$ (two significant figures)".

Answer (score 0):

A 2 sig fig answer is 3.0 x 10^2

Comment: ...or just 300.

Comment: Thank you but isn't that 3 significant figures when you answer 300?

Comment: No. Three significant figures would be 303.